# How to get a bootstrap inline form with varied (small) width inputs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How does one accomplish the following in bootstrap 3 with an inline form?

```
My Label: |__| - |____| - |____|
```

For forms all I can seem to get is:

```
My Label: |_______| - |_______| - |_______|
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your inputs in divs with set width, either by using bootstrap's `.col-sm-x` classes, or use you own widths.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06nhdjzx/1/)